# Receive a readable list in django

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, django-views

When selecting items, this functions works on click:

```
var arr = new Array()
const to_delete = document.getElementById('msgs_to_delete')
function selectMsg(value)
{
    arr.push(value)
    to_delete.value = arr
    console.log(value,'<-->',to_delete.value)
}
```

I successfully receive the information in django (e.g. ['14,11,7,6']), however when trying to iterate through this list (when printing type is says it is a list), I cannot iterate over each number, I appreciate corrections or ways to make it happen. Thank you.

```
  elif 'msgs_to_delete' in request.POST:
     msgs = request.POST.getlist('msgs_to_delete')
     print(msgs)
     print(type(msgs))
     for pk in msgs:
     print(pk,'checking if iterable')
```

Comment: It is a list, a list with *one* element: a comma separated list of items.

Comment: Can you show how you *submit* the values?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike absolutely!                                         
<input type="text" name="msgs_to_delete" id="msgs_to_delete" hidden>
it just came to my mind to use multi select options for submission...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a text box, so it can not contain multiple items. It contains one item: a string that contains a comma separated list of integers. You can parse these back by splitting and mapping:

```
elif 'msgs_to_delete' in request.POST:
    msgs = [int(v) for v in request.POST['msgs_to_delete'].split(',')]
    print(msgs)
    print(type(msgs))
    for pk in msgs:
        print(pk)
```